# How to remove row based on condition of row above or below

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
     chr   leftPos        ZScore1    ZScore2    ZScore3    ZScore4
      1     24352           34         43          19         43
      1     53534           2          1           -1         -9
      2      34            -15         7           -9         -18
      3     3443           -100        -4          4          -9
      3     3445           -100        -1          6          -1
      3     3667            5          -5          9           5
      3      7882          -8          -9          1           3
```

I would like to only keep those rows which have the same chr and have adjacent columns with the ZScore going in the same direction. In other words a row should remain if the row before or after for that chr has the same sign (positive or negative). I would like this to run for all columns with ZS in the column name so that the output ends up just being a number of rows that fulfil the criteria for each row.

For one column the code should result in:

```
     chr   leftPos         ZScore
      1     24352           34
      1     53534           2
      3     3443           -100
      3     3445           -100
```

but the final output should look like

```
         ZScore1    ZScore2    ZScore3    ZScore4
nrow        4         6          4          4


 I have tried bits of code but Im not even really sure how to approach this.
```

I guess I would group by chr and then see if the row above was the same positive or negative as the current row and then see if the row below was the same direction as the current row. Then move to the next row for that chr.

Comment: Yes. That was intentional

Comment: You just said it was intended so why `ZScore2` has seven rows?

Comment: Because each row either has a row above or below that has the same sign

Comment: I guess for `ZScore2` it should be 6 rows and for `ZScore1` 4 rows

Comment: But you are doing it by `chr` and it has only one row when `chr == 2`...

Comment: Oh my goodness. Good point. Will change

Comment: It is not clear how you wanted the result.  Do you need a list with 4 dataset that correspond to each `ZScore`?

Comment: If possible, one dataframe, each column having the name of the ZScore column and an overall score for that column of the number of rows that fulfil the criteria of having to have the same sign as the adjacent row

Comment: For the `ZScore4`, the value would be 4 as well

Comment: Thanks. Also changed

Comment: @user3632206  I updated my post.  Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using the devel version of `data.table` (similar to the approach in @dimitris_ps post).  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5
na.omit(setDT(df)[, {tmp= sign(ZScore)
  .SD[tmp==shift(tmp) | tmp==shift(tmp, type='lead')] },
             by=chr])
#     chr leftPos ZScore
#1:   1   24352     34
#2:   1   53534      2
#3:   3    3443   -100
#4:   3    3445   -100
```

#### Update

We could create a function

```
 f1 <- function(dat, ZCol){
    na.omit(as.data.table(dat)[, {tmp = sign(eval(as.name(ZCol)))
     .SD[tmp==shift(tmp) | tmp==shift(tmp, type='lead')]},
    by=chr])[, list(.N)]}

 nm1 <- paste0('ZScore', 1:4)
 setnames(do.call(cbind,lapply(nm1, function(x) f1(df1, x))), nm1)[]
 #   ZScore1 ZScore2 ZScore3 ZScore4
 #1:       4       6       4       4
```

Or we can use `set`

```
 res <- as.data.table(matrix(0, ncol=4, nrow=1, 
                  dimnames=list(NULL, nm1)))
 for(j in seq_along(nm1)){
   set(res, i=NULL, j=j, value=f1(df1,nm1[j]))
  }
 res
 #   ZScore1 ZScore2 ZScore3 ZScore4
 #1:       4       6       4       4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(chr = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
leftPos = c(24352L, 
53534L, 34L, 3443L, 3445L, 3667L, 7882L), ZScore = c(34L, 2L, 
-15L, -100L, -100L, 5L, -8L)), .Names = c("chr", "leftPos", "ZScore"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

 df1 <- structure(list(chr = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
 leftPos = c(24352L, 
 53534L, 34L, 3443L, 3445L, 3667L, 7882L), ZScore1 = c(34L, 2L, 
 -15L, -100L, -100L, 5L, -8L), ZScore2 = c(43L, 1L, 7L, -4L, -1L, 
 -5L, -9L), ZScore3 = c(19L, -1L, -9L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 1L),
 ZScore4 = c(43L, 
 -9L, -18L, -9L, -1L, 5L, 3L)), .Names = c("chr", "leftPos",
  "ZScore1", "ZScore2", "ZScore3", "ZScore4"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: How would I run this if I had a series of columns in the dataframe eg ZScore1 ZScore2 etc so that it would run for each column in a loop?

Comment: @user3632206  Could you please update your post with an example and expected result as it is a bit unclear from the description.

Comment: with the code above I get the error ‘sign’ not meaningful for factors.

Comment: @user3632206 I think you have `factor` columns.  Please change that to `numeric` by `as.numeric(as.character(`.  Can you try it on the `df1` data in my post?

Comment: OK your data seems to work fine. If I want to make this work for different column names presumably I can use nm1 <- paste0(names(dftbb)) instead of nm1 <- paste0('ZScore', 1:4).

Comment: @user3632206  I think you don't need `paste0` with `names(dftbb)` as it is already a character vector, but I don't know what it has, so I could be wrong.

Comment: The column names could be anything but may be different from each other  eg fggf.56_tr and 3333rr4.

Answer (score 7):

Try this with the package `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
```

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(chr=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
             leftPos=c(24352, 53534, 34, 3443, 3445, 3667, 7882),
             ZScore=c(34, 2, -15, -100, -100, 5, -8))
```

***Code***

```
df %>% group_by(chr) %>% 
   filter(sign(ZScore)==sign(lag(ZScore)) | sign(ZScore)==sign(lead(ZScore))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution which uses `rleid` from the [dev version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
setDT(df)[, indx := .N, by = .(chr, rleid(sign(ZScore)))][indx > 1L]
#    chr leftPos ZScore indx
# 1:   1   24352     34    2
# 2:   1   53534      2    2
# 3:   3    3443   -100    2
# 4:   3    3445   -100    2
```

---

**Edit** (per new data)

```
indx <- paste0('ZScore', 1:4)
temp <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) rleid(sign(x))), .SDcols = indx, by = chr]

Res <- setNames(numeric(length(indx)), indx)
for (i in indx) Res[i] <- length(temp[, .I[.N > 1L], by = c("chr", i)]$V1)
Res
# ZScore1 ZScore2 ZScore3 ZScore4 
#       4       6       4       4
```

Comment: @akrun, hmm yes. I've fixed it. Though interesting behavior. Thanks for noticing

Comment: @akrun it is, but it is doing some unnecessary copies which I would prefer to avoid. Will need to think it thru.

Comment: That works fine in a couple of example data I created. so it avoids the copy, right?

Comment: @akrun I would guess it will be more memory efficient, though it still has an overhead of additional `[`

Answer (score 0):

This is a loop which does what you want.  No fancy packages.  Just check if the row behind and the row ahead match - if they do, move on, otherwise, strip the row and check the same position.

```
chr = c(1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3)
mat = cbind(chr,rnorm(8))

i = 1
while(i <= nrow(mat)){
  if (mat[max(i-1,1),1] != mat[i,1] & mat[min(nrow(mat),i+1),1] != mat[i,1]){
    mat = mat[-i,]
  } else {
    i = i+1
  }
}
```